# Play framework Scala Reporting tool

Tags: scala, playframework

Hi I`m working in a web based application these days and I need to create some reports in that app. Are there any web based report viewing tool can use for scala and play framework? I saw [this](https://gist.github.com/piotrze/1143821) article which using Jasper reports with Playframework and java. Is this possible to do with scala?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, any java library can be used with scala. scala and java are interoperable. Here's an article describing how to work with jasper and [scala](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2013/03/05/jasperreports-and-scala)

Comment: I used jasper reports with spray successfully. Alternatively you can generate simple documents manually with https://github.com/innoveit/play2-pdf